# Do you know how to set the Artist Information to show up in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-app

Do you know how to set the Artist Information to show up in iTunes?  I’m assuming there is some metadata somewhere in the Build Settings, but I was unable to locate it.  Here is an image of the screen you get by right clicking on the application inside iTunes and selecting “Get Info”:(please see the screen shot below)

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Comment: didnt get the screenshot....

Comment: I need minimum 10 reputation to add screen shot. So I was not able to add one.